# Maven exec plugin database <user> does not exist

Tags: java, postgresql, maven

Running exec-maven-plugin i get this error:

```
psql: FATAL:  database <user> does not exist
```

Obviously i don't have database named with username, and I don't want to create one either. Some why maven plugin isn't reading my `-d etsydb`
When in cmd I do `psql -d etsydb -p 5433 -U postgres` it sees the db.
 I got it to work with ant:

```
<exec executable="psql">

    <arg value="-p"/>
    <arg value="5433"/>
    <arg value="-U"/>
    <arg value="postgres"/>
    <arg value="-d"/>
    <arg value="etsydb"/>
    <arg value="-f"/>
    <arg value="src/main/sql/etsydbbackup.sql"/>

</exec>
```

Then I translated it to maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>psql</executable>

                <arg value="-p"/>
                <arg value="5433"/>
                <arg value="-U"/>
                <arg value="postgres"/>
                <arg value="-d"/>
                <arg value="etsydb"/>
                <arg value="-f"/>
                <arg value="src/main/sql/etsydbbackup.sql"/>

            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in Maven there is usually no usage of XML attributes which brings me to the following:

You have to use the following:

```
   <arguments>
       <argument>-p</argument>
       <argument>5433</argument>
       <argument>-U</argument>
       <argument>postgres</argument>
       <argument>-d</argument>
       <argument>etsysdb</argument>
       <argument>-f</argument>
       <argument>src/main/sql/etsysdbbackup.sql</argument>
   </arguments>
```

Comment: ou.. yeah ofc.. need to take a break i guess :D thanks!